# Cannot upload image Vue

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, upload, axios, nuxt.js

So I am using a package called [vue-picture-input](https://github.com/alessiomaffeis/vue-picture-input) and Im uploading the image using axios. My vue file contains this element:

```
 <picture-input
  ref="pictureInput"
  :width="500"
  :height="500"
  :removable="true"
  :custom-strings="{
    upload: '<h1>Upload it!</h1>',
    drag: 'Drag and drop your image here'
  }"
  button-class="ui button primary"
  remove-button-class="ui red button"
  accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif"
  @change="onChanged"
  @remove="onRemoved"
/>
```

That is uploaded using this method:

```
uploadAPI('pages/', this.image, name)
          .then(response=>{
            console.log(response)
            if (response.data.success){
              this.image = '';
              console.log("Image uploaded successfully Harambe");
            }
          })
          .catch(err=>{
            console.error(err);
          });
```

I have all of the values in the parameters and the API accepts those parameters and confirms it has them. The uploadAPI file:
import axios from 'axios';
import configuration from '../../configs/config'

```
export default function (urn, file, name) {
  if (typeof urn !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError(`Expected a string, got ${typeof url}`);
  }

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(name, file);
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  };

  let url = configuration.SERVER.uploadURL + urn

  return axios.post(url, formData, config);
};
```

The url points to `http://localhost:4000/static/uploads`. But nothing gets uploaded. There seem to be no problems with CORS and no errors are caught. It's weird to me. The response to the axois request is a status 200 with the data:

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-n-head="">
  <head>
    <title data-n-head="true">nuxt-sever</title><meta data-n-head="true" charset="utf-8"/><meta data-n-head="true" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="description" name="description" content="The Spiciest Nuxt.js Project"/><link data-n-head="true" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/runtime.js" as="script" /><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/commons.app.js" as="script" /><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/vendors.app.js" as="script" /><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.js" as="script" />
  </head>
  <body data-n-head="">
    <div id="__nuxt"><style>#nuxt-loading {  visibility: hidden;  opacity: 0;  position: absolute;  left: 0;  right: 0;  top: 0;  bottom: 0;  display: flex;  justify-content: center;  align-items: center;  flex-direction: column;  animation: nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;  -webkit-animation: nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  overflow: hidden;}@keyframes nuxtLoadingIn {  0% {visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;  }  20% {visibility: visible;opacity: 0;  }  100% {visibility: visible;opacity: 1;  }}@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoadingIn {  0% {visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;  }  20% {visibility: visible;opacity: 0;  }  100% {visibility: visible;opacity: 1;  }}#nuxt-loading>div,#nuxt-loading>div:after {  border-radius: 50%;  width: 5rem;  height: 5rem;}#nuxt-loading>div {  font-size: 10px;  position: relative;  text-indent: -9999em;  border: .5rem solid #F5F5F5;  border-left: .5rem solid #fff;  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);  transform: translateZ(0);  -webkit-animation: nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;  animation: nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;}#nuxt-loading.error>div {  border-left: .5rem solid #ff4500;  animation-duration: 5s;}@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoading {  0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);  }  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);  }}@keyframes nuxtLoading {  0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);  }  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);  }}</style><script>window.addEventListener('error', function () {  var e = document.getElementById('nuxt-loading');  if (e) e.className += ' error';});</script><div id="nuxt-loading" aria-live="polite" role="status"><div>Loading...</div></div><!-- https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders --></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/commons.app.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/vendors.app.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

it doesn't print out any error and the response.data.success is not true. I am a bit lost and would appreciate if you could assist me in debugging this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Might be a problem with the server. Are you sure that `http://localhost:4000/static/uploads` accepts files?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: And what is your upload handling code? Nuxt dont handle upload, you need a backend for this

Comment: How would I handle it?

Comment: Oh so im just sending a request for upload but the server has no way of receiving it?

Comment: You need to have a backend server that will handle your upload.

Comment: @Hakorou exactly

Comment: Could you direct me on how to do this ?
`uploadRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
 // i'm lost
})`

Comment: Its totally depends on your backend. https://scotch.io/tutorials/express-file-uploads-with-multer

Answer (score 0):

Had to receive the file on backend with multer